# Lazily loading an 11 MB file in the browser

Tags: ajax, json, memory-management, browser

I'm building a quiz backed by a lot of Census data, and I would really like to power it with flat files rather than worry about a database and servers. (More on the [case for flat files](https://source.opennews.org/en-US/articles/case-flat-files-big-data-projects/) here.) The uncompressed JSON file I need for the file part of the quiz is currently 11MB.

Right now, I'm making an AJAX request for the file right away, but not using it until the user has completed the quiz, which will take about 1 minute.

I realize this is a bit of a subjective question, but I'm wondering how much this is pushing the envelope when it comes to supporting a wide variety of modern phones and computers in 2015. I'm worried less about the bandwidth than about the memory and processing power in the device. The code parses through all the data, matches entries to user responses, and computes a result.

**TL;DR**

Is it crazy to AJAX an 11B JSON file if I don't need it for about 60 seconds? (I'll check to make sure I have it when the time comes, of course)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't split the json into relevant parts and only load the next chunk when needed? Personally I'd say no to loading in huge files like that. 11MB for json is gigantic.

Comment: I can, it's just a lot of really annoying logic because the slicing and dicing is different for every user.

Comment: Annoying at least is temporary. Spend a little time writing the logic for intelligent splitting and serving or let your quiz slaughter finite data plans forever. Chances are your users would never know, and most may not even understand how 11 megs compares against their data plans anyhow. In general I like to say if it aint broke, don't fix it. So if your quiz is working, then call it done.

Comment: Closing the loop here, I did it the tedious way and did not load this file!